# In PHP, how do I showing selected values with select2(Jquery pulgin)

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2

I need multiple values in select2's select box, but it selecting the last one.
I can insert `apple`, `tomato` into the database, but only `tomato` displays in select2 in the browser.

This is the code that I have, that is only selecting one value for the select, not multiple.

```php
<?php if ($views['mb_medical']) $medi_arr = explode('|', $views['mb_medical']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($medi_arr); $i++) { ?>
        <select class="medical_subject" name="mb_medical[]" id="mb_medical" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="apple" <?php if($medi_arr[$i] == 'apple') echo 'selected'; ?>>apple</option>
            <option value="tomato" <?php if($medi_arr[$i] == 'tomato') echo 'selected'; ?>>tomato</option>
            <option value="banana" <?php if($medi_arr[$i] == 'banana') echo 'selected'; ?>>banana</option>
            <option value="melon" <?php if($medi_arr[$i] == 'melon') echo 'selected'; ?>>melon</option>
        </select>
                
<?php } ?>
```

[image: select2 showing that tomato has been selected, but not any others.]

In picture, select2 is missing `apple`, but it does have `tomato`.
I have already checked the `$medi_arr[$i]` outputs correclty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding a sample code so you can use this code in your code to full-fill your desired task.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<select name="category" class="select2 select2-offscreen" id="category" style="width:100%" data-placeholder="Select Fields" tabindex="-1" multiple>
<option value="">Select Category</option>
<option value="1">Business</option>
<option value="7">Education</option>
<option value="5" selected="selected">Environment</option>
<option value="3" selected="selected">Health</option>
<option value="11">Movies</option>
<option value="4">Science</option>
<option value="2">Sports</option>
<option value="6">Tech</option>
<option value="10">Top Stories</option>      
</select>

<script>
$("#category").select2();
</script>
```

Comment: I got to know the problem with my code. there seems to be a problem between 'select2' and array list with explode. I'm going to try again...

Answer (score 1):

it's work finally.

```
<?php if ($views['mb_medical']) {
  $medi_arr = explode('|', $views['mb_medical']); ?>
  
  <select class="medical_subject" name="mb_medical[]" id="mb_medical" multiple>
      <option value="apple" 
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($medi_arr); $i++) {
        if($medi_arr[$i] == 'apple') echo 'selected';} ?>>apple
      </option>
      <option value="tomato" 
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($medi_arr); $i++) {
        if($medi_arr[$i] == 'tomato') echo 'selected';} ?>>tomato
      </option>
      <option value="banana" 
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($medi_arr); $i++) { 
        if($medi_arr[$i] == 'banana') echo 'selected';} ?>>banana
      </option>
      <option value="melon" 
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($medi_arr); $i++) { 
        if($medi_arr[$i] == 'melon') echo 'selected';} ?>>melon
      </option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to write all options manually code below is dynamiccaly generates options pulled out from database:

```html
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-select" id="Labels" name="Labels" multiple="multiple" data-width="100%">
  <?php 
  if ($products["labels"]) {
       $label_arr = explode('|', $products["labels"]);
  } 
  ?>
  <?php foreach ($labels as $label): ?>
  <option value="<?= $label['label'] ?>" 
  <?php if ($label_arr) { 
    for ($i=0 ; $i < count($label_arr); $i++) { 
      if ($label_arr[$i]==$ label[ 'label']) echo 'selected'; 
      } 
     } 
  ?> >
    <?= $label['label'] ?>
  </option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

</select>
```